# Podfile.lock versions and pod [podfile] --version numbers are different

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to update three of the pods in my podfile. I cannot figure out why the Podfile.lock version numbers and the version numbers obtained by

`pod [podfile] --version`

command give different results. I tried cleaning the pod cache and removing all of the files in the Pod directory.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `Podfile.lock` file explains why the versions are chosen.  Share it here if it's not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Change deployment target, e.g `platform :ios, '13.2'`
In terminal, make sure you change path to the correct directory before running `pod update`

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, the files were being updated. The commands

```
pod GooglePlaces --version
pod GoogleMaps --version
pod --version
```

and all other pod [podfile] --versions are returning the same value. I think it is the value of the cocoa pods versions I have installed.